# Layout : Splash screen background is still showing when new layout comes

Tags: android, layout, splash-screen

I have a problem in layout. In my activity at first I show a splash screen and after that based on some condition i need to show different layouts.when i display one layout it looks like transparent white (like splash view) and other one is ok because its background color is matching with it.
When ever i press on transparent white view(text view) it looks normal. That is it acts as button in the sense on pressing and releasing different views.

I tried with giving background color but still problem exist.Unfortunately i need to give white color only for that view.

Can any one help me to change that transparent white showing in my new layout

this is layout of view having background problem

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="@color/white"  
 >

<ScrollView 
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
 android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
 >
 <RelativeLayout 
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     >
   <TextView
     android:id="@+id/abc"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"

      />
     </RelativeLayout>   
 </ScrollView>

<RelativeLayout 
     android:id="@+id/button_layout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"

    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
    >

<Button 
    android:id="@+id/btn1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:text="@string/btn1"
    android:background="@drawable/btn1"


    />
 <Button 
    android:id="@+id/btn2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:text="@string/btn2"
    android:background="@drawable/btn2" 
   />

</RelativeLayout>
```

In code

```
oncreate(){
setcontentview(splashscreen)
setview()
}

void setview(){
if(condition1){
            setContentView(R.layout.a1);

}
else{
       setContentView(R.layout.a2);
}
}
```

Comment: Have you finished your splashscreen activity ?

Comment: Are you invalidating the other view?  Why not set the other views invisible and the one you are using visible.  Need more meat on this question.

Comment: @JibranKhan in main activity splash is using . i need to change the view in same activity itself not in a new one

Comment: @digiholic how to invalidate a view?

Comment: I will suggest to have a separate activity for Splashscreen

Comment: Korcholis answer is roughly how I do my splash screens too.  Sjk, sorry when I posted originally the code wasn't up.  Maybe you could set your splashscreen.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE) depending on what kind of view it is.  What I am saying is that maybe the screen is not removing the old view and just drawing over it.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you just move to another activity when the splash ends? Like [this](http://www.itcuties.com/android/how-to-create-android-splash-screen/). Just for the sake of SO, I copy the code of that page here:

```
package com.itcuties.tutorial.android;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;


public class SplashActivity extends Activity {

   private static String TAG = SplashActivity.class.getName();
   private static long SLEEP_TIME = 5;    // Sleep for some time

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

      this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);    // Removes title bar
      this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);    // Removes notification bar

      setContentView(R.layout.splash);

      // Start timer and launch main activity
      IntentLauncher launcher = new IntentLauncher();
      launcher.start();
   }

   private class IntentLauncher extends Thread {
      @Override
      /**
       * Sleep for some time and than start new activity.
       */
      public void run() {
         try {
            // Sleeping
            Thread.sleep(SLEEP_TIME*1000);
         } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
         }

         // Start main activity
         Intent intent = new Intent(SplashActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
         SplashActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
         SplashActivity.this.finish();
      }
   }
}
```